# No response from Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Android newly here. I am working on a popular movies app that fetches some movie data from moved.org and display to users when tapping on movie thumbnail. Recently, I have been working on setting up retrofit in my app for two weeks. I am trying to use MVVM pattern. My goals is to get response from api.moviedb.org so that, eventually, I can display movie posters in recycler view. For some reason, I am not able to get any response from the api call using retrofit. I think I did something wrong with setting up retrofit but can't find out how I messed up... I feel like I am hard stuck.. Any help from experienced android developers would be much appreciated:)

[Github link to my project](https://github.com/kdy304g/Popuar-Movie-app/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/popularmovie)

On create method in MainActivity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvMovies);
        movieViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieViewModel.class);
//        Log.d("viewmodel", String.valueOf(movieViewModel));
        movieViewModel.getMoviesLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<MovieResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(MovieResult movieResult) {
                Log.d("movieResult", String.valueOf(movieResult));
            }
        });
    }
```

ViewModel Class:

```
public class MovieViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<MovieResult> movieLiveData;
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    public MovieViewModel(@NonNull Application application){
        super(application);
    }

    public void init(){
        if (movieLiveData != null){
            return;
        }
        movieRepository = MovieRepository.getInstance();
        movieLiveData = movieRepository.getMovies("api_key_here");
    }

    public LiveData<MovieResult> getMoviesLiveData() {
        init();
        return movieLiveData;
    }
}
```

Respository:

```
public class MovieRepository {
    private static MovieRepository movieRepository;

    public static MovieRepository getInstance(){
        if (movieRepository == null){
            movieRepository = new MovieRepository();
        }
        return movieRepository;
    }

    private GetMovieService service;

    public MovieRepository(){
        service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetMovieService.class);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MovieResult> getMovies(String api){
        Log.d("getmovies","called");
        final MutableLiveData<MovieResult> movieData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        service.getMovieResult(api).enqueue(new Callback<MovieResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResult> call, Response<MovieResult> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    movieData.setValue(response.body());
                    Log.d("debug", String.valueOf(movieData));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResult> call, Throwable t) {
                movieData.setValue(null);
                Log.d("onfailure","why");
            }
        });
        return movieData;
    }
}
```

RetrofitInstance:

```
public class RetrofitInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

GetMovieService.Java

```
public interface GetMovieService {
    @GET("movie/popular")
    Call<MovieResult> getMovieResult(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);
}
```

logical:

[log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWsZ5.jpg)

Comment: Do you get any logs in `onFailure`? Also, log the else part of `if (response.isSuccessful())`

Comment: I get log for onFailure. I added some log statements to else part of ```if (response.isSuccessful())``` but that doesn't log anything..

Comment: Please post the logs from onFailure.

Comment: 2020-05-26 18:26:02.541 28460-28460/com.example.popularmovie D/movieResult: null
2020-05-26 18:26:02.541 28460-28460/com.example.popularmovie D/onfailure: why

Comment: Please edit the question and post the entire error log. It's hard to help without all the information. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The problem was using "http://"... I changed to "https://" and this works like a charm. Thank you for those who invested time in this!